# Creating new FTP user via SSH

Tags: ssh, putty

I am trying the following cmd

```
    useradd -u 500 -s /bin/false -d /home/username
```

Putty returns a whole list of parameters with descriptions after

```
Usage: useradd [options] LOGIN
...(
```

The parameters I specify are also described - as copied/pasted below.

- -u - User ID for the user, which must be unique and greater than 499
- -s - User's login shell, which defaults to /bin/bash
- -d - home directory for the new user account

My server details

```
Linux 2.6.18-308.11.1.el5 GNU/Linux
(Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
Centos
```

I dont know where to go from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your useradd command is missing the username.

Add username as the last argument and try again.

```
useradd -u 500 -s /bin/false -d /home/username username
```

Comment: I thought my username would be 500, trying your script now, THanks

Comment: No, 500 is the numeric id, but not the username (or login name). Take a look at /etc/passwd (cat /etc/passwd). Your user has a unique user and group id. The numeric id is stored on file permissions, etc. If you leave off -u then useradd will autoassign one.

Comment: I am following this as well. How would I give username a password?